# Solve for x : n**x + x = 0 using binary search

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, binary-search, equation

I want to solve for x (up to 6 decimal places) in the equation: n**x + x = 0. I want to do this using Binary Search.

I used the below code to get the square root of a positive integer, 'n'. Need to apply the same logic to solve the above problem somehow.

```
n=int(input())

#find square root of n here
def sqroot(n):
    l = 0
    r = n
    while abs(l-r) > 10**(-5):
        mid = (l+r)/2
        if mid**2 > n:
            r = mid
        else:
            l = mid
    return round(mid,4)
print('%.4f' % sqroot(n))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary Search : Equation Solving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254152/binary-search-equation-solving)

Answer (score 2):

The function seems to be monotonically increasing so binary search can be applied in the same way as for the square root.

In your function `n` was the target, now it is 0 and `n` is a parameter.

Note that this function seems to have a it's zero in the negative, so do not forget to extend the search space.

```
n = int(input())

def binarySearch(n):
    # n is the parameter
    l = -10
    r = 10

    while abs(l - r) > 10**(-5):
        mid = (l + r) / 2
        # Compute the value of the function and compare against 0.0
        if (n**mid + mid) > 0.0:
            r = mid
        else:
            l = mid
    return round(mid, 4)

print('%.4f' % binarySearch(n))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
n = int(input())
```

def binarySearch(n):
# n is the parameter
l = -10
r = 10

```
while abs(l - r) > 10**(-6):
    mid = (l + r) / 2
    # Compute the value of the function and compare against 0.0
    if (n**mid + mid) > 0.0:
        r = mid
    else:
        l = mid
return round(mid, 6)
```

print('%.6f' % binarySearch(n))

Comment: There is no need to repeat an answer that was given 8 months earlier.